# What should be a Select query with SUM calculation of a column for every row?

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a Column Amount, I will get multiple rows with different values in that Amount column.
I need a select query such that I get the SUM of all these amounts as an output.

Thanks And Regards

Comment: Is this question asking how to query into a *dynamic set of columns*?

Comment: @pst: I think he means "I have a column `Amount`".

Comment: Do you want a SUM for each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
SELECT SUM(t.amount)
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

...will return a single value, the sum of all the values in the amount column.  If you want to see the sum for different groups of values, you need to add a GROUP BY clause to the query:

```
  SELECT SUM(t.amount)
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
GROUP BY t.column
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the SUM aggregrate function:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS Total
FROM yourtable
```

The result will contain a single row, containing the total sum for the column.